# Setting destination for secure file uploads php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am using the following php file upload class to upload my files in relative security. I'll be adding more security features later:

http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

My problem is though, I would like to upload my file to the folder www.mysite.com/upload which I've already pre-created ready to take the files.

The only problem is I don't know how to set it properly to do that. I've confirmed the form is submitting fine. Here's what I tried to use:

```
$handle = new class_upload($_FILES['image_upload']);
  if ($handle->uploaded) {
      $handle->file_new_name_body   = 'image_resized';
      $handle->image_resize         = true;
      $handle->image_x              = 100;
      $handle->image_ratio_y        = true;
      $handle->process('/home/user/upload');
      if ($handle->processed) {
          echo 'image resized';
          $handle->clean();
      } else {
          echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
      }
  }
```

I get the error:

> "Destination directory can't be created. Can't carry on a process."

What do I set for `$handle->process('/home/user/upload');` so that it will upload into the correct directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message suggests that the user your webserver is running under may not have permissions to create directories... so it would imply the directory you've created is not being targeted.

You'll need full path to this folder... one way to get it would be to use:

```
$handle->process($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/upload/');
```

I'd try and avoid this though as the $_SERVER variable can be tampered with or can be inaccurate in general.

The better approach imho would be:

```
$handle->process(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/upload/');
```

And ensure the folder you've created has writable permissions for the web-server's user/group.

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat! I used echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; to find out the path and then put it in using hardcode. Always best to hardcode if you can things I think. Definitely right about the tampering of arrays. :)

Comment: Perfect solution if you're not using the site on multiple hosts - the realpath method also works pretty well to compute the root relevant to the file you call the function in. Glad to have helped & have a good weekend. Would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: You too thanks! I always accept...just have to wait for the damn timer

Comment: @AmyNeville there's no concern in "tampering arrays". He didn't say that. The only thing you should be careful using is the $_SERVER superglobal array, because you can't always trust its values, sometimes they depend on what an admin configured, and yeah, values can be spoofed. Hardcoding things is generally bad practice and you should avoid it as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, what you are looking for is `$handle->process(dirname(__FILE__).'/home');`, assuming the calling script is directly in the web root folder.